# Kaldi-for-Dummies Tutorial -- run.sh script throwing "no such files in directory" error while Preparing Acoustic Data

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, kaldi

I am trying to replicate http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/kaldi_for_dummies.html to get started onto an Automatic Speech Recognition solution i am trying to develop. I followed all the instructions within this Tutorial and then finally ran **run.sh** script. However i got the following errors in the terminal.

```
===== PREPARING ACOUSTIC DATA =====

./run.sh: line 22: data/train/spk2utt: No such file or directory
./run.sh: line 23: data/test/spk2utt: No such file or directory

===== FEATURES EXTRACTION =====

steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj 1 --cmd run.pl data/train exp/make_mfcc/train mfcc
make_mfcc.sh: no such file data/train/wav.scp
steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj 1 --cmd run.pl data/test exp/make_mfcc/test mfcc
make_mfcc.sh: no such file data/test/wav.scp
steps/compute_cmvn_stats.sh data/train exp/make_mfcc/train mfcc
make_cmvn.sh: no such file data/train/feats.scp
steps/compute_cmvn_stats.sh data/test exp/make_mfcc/test mfcc
make_cmvn.sh: no such file data/test/feats.scp

===== PREPARING LANGUAGE DATA =====

utils/prepare_lang.sh data/local/dict <UNK> data/local/lang data/lang
Checking data/local/dict/silence_phones.txt ...
--> reading data/local/dict/silence_phones.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/dict/silence_phones.txt is OK

Checking data/local/dict/optional_silence.txt ...
--> reading data/local/dict/optional_silence.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/dict/optional_silence.txt is OK

Checking data/local/dict/nonsilence_phones.txt ...
--> reading data/local/dict/nonsilence_phones.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/dict/nonsilence_phones.txt is OK

Checking disjoint: silence_phones.txt, nonsilence_phones.txt
--> disjoint property is OK.

Checking data/local/dict/lexicon.txt
--> reading data/local/dict/lexicon.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/dict/lexicon.txt is OK

Checking data/local/dict/extra_questions.txt ...
--> data/local/dict/extra_questions.txt is empty (this is OK)
--> SUCCESS [validating dictionary directory data/local/dict]

**Creating data/local/dict/lexiconp.txt from data/local/dict/lexicon.txt
utils/prepare_lang.sh: line 468: fstarcsort: command not found
utils/prepare_lang.sh: line 466: fstcompile: command not found
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name=1 mode='w' encoding='latin-1'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

===== LANGUAGE MODEL CREATION =====
===== MAKING lm.arpa =====

data/local/corpus.txt: No such file or directory

===== MAKING G.fst =====

./run.sh: line 75: arpa2fst: command not found

===== MONO TRAINING =====

steps/train_mono.sh --nj 1 --cmd run.pl data/train data/lang exp/mono
cat: data/lang/oov.int: No such file or directory
```

Here i am trying to understand the error thrown under the first section "Preparing Acoustic Data"

```
===== PREPARING ACOUSTIC DATA =====

./run.sh: line 22: data/train/spk2utt: No such file or directory
./run.sh: line 23: data/test/spk2utt: No such file or directory
```

I have made utt2spk file within the train and test data folders but i cannot understand why this error is coming? I debugged run.sh script and i found this line where i might be having the problem.

```
# Making spk2utt files
utils/utt2spk_to_spk2utt.pl data/train/utt2spk > data/train/spk2utt
utils/utt2spk_to_spk2utt.pl data/test/utt2spk > data/test/spk2utt
```

Can somebody help me troubleshoot this issue? I am using Linux Ubuntu xfce. I have g++,gcc and all dependent packages installed (not ATLAS).

Comment: The real error is above, you need to check the full log. Most likely you had problems to download the data.

Comment: Hi Nikolay,

Above is all the logs that we get when i run ./run.sh script in kaldi/egs/digits directory. Can you make some sense out of it? It would be of great help if you could guide me to a direction where i can move ahead. Is there something else you would need to understand my problem? I have followed Kaldi-for-dummies tutorial exactly.

Comment: Check internals to see why it failed to download the data, maybe some setup on your network prevents download.

Comment: Hi @Nitinshukla, have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Aidos Yes I was able to get over this hurdle.